# Link to static file in Yesod that doesn't have Haskell identifier

Tags: haskell, yesod

Given a default Yesod scaffold, with file upload implemented by moving the uploaded file into the `static` directory, how do I link to the file in the static directory? For normal static files, the `staticFiles` splice will generate an identifier I can reference, but for user uploaded files obviously I cannot hardcode these identifiers. I can do this by manually using a `#{}` splice, but I was hoping there might be something a little more typesafe, even the only checkable component is that I used the `static/` prefix correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`staticFiles` generates a bunch of identifiers with type `Route Static`. Unfortunately, Haddock doesn't display the information on associated type families, so you can't see the constructor in the docs, but the only constructor available is `StaticRoute`:

```
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-static/Yesod/Static.hs#L142
```

The two fields are the path info and the query string parameters. So to create a link to `/static/foo/bar?baz=bin`, you could use:

```
StaticRoute ["foo", "bar"] [("baz", "bin")]
```

Usually creating a query string parameter isn't necessary, but `staticFiles` will use it to insert a hash value for cache-busting purposes.

Comment: Important addendum: since Static is a subsite, to actually embed the link your App, you'll need to wrap StaticRoute with StaticR (or whatever your embedding constructor of the subsite is). But otherwise, this works great.